# htaccess redirect <hostname>/?area=0 to <hostname>/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am simply trying to redirect /?area=0 link to / .. hostname can be anything. I have tried:

```
redirectMatch 301 /?area=0 /index.php
RewriteRule ^/?area=0$ /index.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also tried with some little variations, but doesn't redirect or causes internal server error. Redirection only must happen when area is 0 and url does not contain other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^area=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php? [L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks for tips and example. Works just like it should.